# Unknown variable in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

I am trying to understand a function on this site: http://www.coloplast.nl/speedicath-compact-set-nl-nl.aspx.

The function is valtech.readmode.getRmIdFromUrl declared by the following block:

```
function(t) {
    var i = n.deparam.fragment(),
        r = i && i.section ? i.section.replace(/[^_]*_/, "") : 0;
    return r === 0 && (t || !o) && (i = n.deparam.querystring(), r = s()), r
}
```

I don't understand where the "n" object comes from. I have checked the chrome console, but can't find any object called "n". Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the file you will see

```
function(n)
```

You can take the rest from there.

Pretty print feature in your debugger will help. But the files from been compressed so have fun figuring out what variables actually mean.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is a global variable or defined in some other js file.

If some other js file is included in this file, then this variable may be in that file.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of javascript on that page... have you checked all the javascript referenced in the page? That includes all the inline script AND every script referenced. For convenience, I've made you a list of the referenced scripts in order of appearance (if I have more time later, I might go through them myself):

```
http://www.coloplast.nl/WebResource.axd?d=bY0OOHwLEVo6bDBNGb8HaFqVe_XttRuElND8IC1BZzfU11zfPw19ILOblYEbIeCL6Of0KmpUNojBqf9t0keS1mBlGDmBC7gZs90pIm5CRz79Pax8U0QamyFspryuadHmCUBCEfC-bk_Hn5OXzRVIZz-Xy3C8GY5U2sioj0N1qno1&t=635211838780000000
http://www.coloplast.nl/Custom/Ui/baseline/js/modernizr.js
http://www.coloplast.nl/WebResource.axd?d=MhLP7bmL7rRi7HOlL-F6QjZE7z6uFAus97w8Kks8FqDMMuvCPMw3vZ6kM8pCL3n6klBQoWe856WnY3V_cRMfHU5EarlrdRVE-oNHXU0_5g41&t=634808697229534010
http://www.coloplast.nl/cassette.axd/script/6c60b0617161675c6f9b24d23519fcbf077b6cb6/MasterScriptBundleBody
http://www.coloplast.nl/cassette.axd/script/575df033980c8d6b073b9c904d60ebdb660f04c2/KnockoutScriptBundle
http://www.coloplast.nl/cassette.axd/script/19255108742242ed95de2e764d7833305383231f/ProductDetailScriptBundle
http://www.coloplast.nl/cassette.axd/script/b9d055aa4fc8106b61f915f4e109c60197c5f3c6/ReadModeScriptBundle
http://www.coloplast.nl/cassette.axd/script/09da679c2d1ad6d666dc31ac3585e8e85197fec8/VideoBannerScriptBundle
http://www.coloplast.nl/cassette.axd/script/aeaf4af2bed4f09871c7e889d89b214d083c6096/YassScriptBundle
http://www.coloplast.nl/cassette.axd/script/b4a5f3ebf502b1d67e99aa4ab6ef3876d0c8be12/MWRScriptBundle
http://www.coloplast.nl/cassette.axd/script/202bb726686bb38bc9d7938ac5e38d1985b39d0a/LoginScriptBundle
```